# Batch file to copy and launch executable by architecture

Tags: batch-file, login-script

I'm trying to create a login batch file to copy 32-bit and 64-bit executable files from a server to a user's local machine then execute those files based on OS type/architecture. This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to be working as it only launches the 32-bit file and is not detecting and launching the 64-bit file. I'm new to this so any assistance will be appreciated.

```
@echo off
c:
MD c:\temp
xcopy \\server\NETLOGON\SEPRemoval c:\temp /e /y
cd c:\temp
if /i "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "x86" goto ARCH32
if /i "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "AMD64" goto ARCH64


:ARCH32
start /wait SEPprep.exe
goto done

:ARCH64
start /wait SEPprep64.exe
goto done

:done

timeout 15
cd \
del c:\temp /q
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally came up with that works with assistance from some guys over at the Microsoft Scripting Guys forum:

```
@echo off
c:
MD c:\temp
xcopy \\server\NETLOGON\SEPRemoval c:\temp\ /e /y
cd /d c:\temp
if {%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%} EQU {} (
  set TRUE_ARCH=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
   start /b /wait SEPprep.exe
   goto Done
) else (
  set TRUE_ARCH=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%
  start /b /wait SEPprep64.exe
  goto Done
)
echo Processor Architecture is %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%

:Done
timeout 15
rd /s /q c:\temp 1>nul 2>nul
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your batch file, it's that you're relying on an environment variable that doesn't do what you think it does.

On my 64-bit Windows 7 machine, `ENV` shows:

```
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
```

...so relying on PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE to differentiate between 32 & 64 bit machines isn't going to work.

There *is* a [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556009) on the topic.

Fix your method of detecting processor architecture, and you should be OK.

Comment: A search for "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" in StackOverflow finds 197 results... chances are _somebody_ has posted the exact code you need!

Answer (score 0):

Check out `systeminfo`

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\systeminfo.exe
```

Or something simple like

```
if defined ProgramFiles(x86)
```

This will check if the ProgramFiles(x86) environment variable is defined (only defined on 64 bit versions of Windows).